# Error: "Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::update does not exist." How do I update multiple row of data to table? [Eloquent]

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

So I have this

```
        $master_item_id = array_map('intval', $request->master_item_id);
        $quantity = array_map('intval', $request->quantity);
        $price = MasterItem::whereIn('id', $master_item_id)->get('price');

        foreach ($master_item_id as $key => $no) {
            $input['price'] = $price[$key]['price'];
            $input['quantity'] = $quantity[$key];
            $subtotal[] = $input['price'] * $input['quantity'];
        }

        $total_price = array_sum($subtotal);

        // Update transaction
        $transaction = Transaction::find($id);
        $transaction->total_price = $total_price;
        $transaction->last_edited_by = Auth::user()->name;
        $transaction->update();

        // Update transaction_item
        foreach ($master_item_id as $key => $no) {
            $transaction = Transaction::find($id);
            $transaction->transaction_item->transaction_id= $transaction->id;
            $transaction->transaction_item->master_item_id = $no;
            $transaction->transaction_item->quantity = $quantity[$key];
            $transaction->transaction_item->price = $price[$key]['price'];
            $transaction->transaction_item->update();
        }
```

My Model

```
    // Transaction Model
    public function transaction_item()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(TransactionItem::class, 'transaction_id');
    }
    public function item()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(MasterItem::class, 'transaction_item', 'transaction_id', 'master_item_id');
    }
```

```
    // TransactionItem Model
    public function transaction()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Transaction::class, 'transaction_id');
    }
    public function item()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(MasterItem::class, 'master_item_id');
    }
```

```
    // MasterItem Model
    public function transaction_item()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(TransactionItem::class, 'master_item_id');
    }
```

My table structure

```
transaction: id(pk), total_price
transaction_item: id(pk), transaction_id(fk), master_item_id(fk), quantity, price
master_item: id(pk), item_name, price
```

When I try to update it popped up error

```
Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::update does not exist.
```

And the error highlighted this line of my code

```
$transaction->transaction_item->update();
```

How do I edit/update multiple rows of data? And is my relationship in my model correct? Thanks!

Comment: `transaction_item` returns a Collection of `TransactionItem` instances, and `Collection` don't have an `update()` method. Should that return a single instance (i.e. be a `hasOne()`)? Or do you want to update all `transaction_items`? If so, you have to loop `foreach ($transaction->transcation_item as $transactionItem){ // set properties $transactionItem->save() }`

Comment: fyi, typo in `...transcation_item->transaction_id`

Comment: Can you please elaborate? I do want to update all my `transaction_items`. And by `foreach ($transaction->transcation_item as $transactionItem)`, I need to replace my `foreach ($master_item_id as $key => $no)`? And yeah didn't notice there that I have a typo

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the `update()` method on an `Eloquent\Collection` which isn't working. You can try this instead:

```
// Update transaction_item
foreach ($master_item_id as $key => $no) {
    $transaction = Transaction::find($id);
    $transaction->transaction_item()->update([
        'transaction_id' => $transaction->id,
        'master_item_id' => $no,
        'quantity' => $quantity[$key],
        'price' => $price[$key]['price']
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get `$transaction->transaction_item()` instead `$transaction->transaction_item` you became `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany` and than you can calling the `update()` method.

```
$transaction->transaction_item()->update(['some_field' => 'some_variable']);
```